# In Magento: Where do you actually store the information of the shelf location code of a product

Tags: magento2, orders, simple-product

I am currently reading about Magento2 and considering to use it to setup an online store for products I have on stock.

One thing I couldn't find yet in the documentation is the handling of the physical bin location of a product. **Where in Magento do you map a simple product with an actual physical location?**

I mean not only which warehouse but where in the warehouse, so that the picker sees the order and knows instantly where to look for the items to be picked up.

**And how do you handle the fact that an item might lie around in different locations within a warehouse e.g. when you are working with a Chaotic Storage approach.**

Answer (score 0):

It is not implemented for the Magento MSI feature yet. Should add a custom "shelf" attribute for source items.